# ag-grid and AOT build

Tags: angular, npm, ag-grid, aot

Getting this error when trying to do an `aot build`, wondering if anyone has come across it

```
Error at /Users/liambayly/WebDev/XPO/ng-xpo-board/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/filter/baseFilter.d.ts:21:31: Class 'BaseFilter<T, P, M>' incorrectly implements interface 'IFilterComp'.
  Types of property 'afterGuiAttached' are incompatible.
    Type '(params: IAfterGuiAttachedParams) => void' is not assignable to type '((params?: IFilterAfterGuiAttachedParams | undefined) => void) | undefined'.
      Type '(params: IAfterGuiAttachedParams) => void' is not assignable to type '(params?: IFilterAfterGuiAttachedParams | undefined) => void'.
        Types of parameters 'params' and 'params' are incompatible.
          Type 'IFilterAfterGuiAttachedParams | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IAfterGuiAttachedParams'.
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IAfterGuiAttachedParams'.
```